# Software to create videos from multiple songs

Tags: video, youtube, software, windows-movie-maker, music

I have a lot of songs that I want to upload to YouTube.

I already uploaded close to 1000 videos. Those videos were created using Windows Movie Maker (for each song) + a macro to automate everything. (I used macros when I need to upload an album, but instead of a video with the whole album, I uploaded each song then created a playlist of the album in YouTube.)

Most of the songs are from albums, so it's a lot of work and time to do it manually. Plus Movie Maker is giving me nightmares... Errors coming up, freezes, etc.

So I would like to know if there is a software out there that could do this easily:

1. Select one image for the video track.
2. Select, let's say, 10 songs.
3. Create 10 videos with that image, and those songs. Each song to each video.

Or create just one video with the whole album, and then split the file into multiple videos with each song.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Putting together an image and an audio file and exporting the result to a youtube friendly format shouldn't take more than 10 minutes per song in Adobe Premiere Pro...

Comment: For an album with 20 tracks for example, that would be like 3 hours to create the videos plus the time to upload it. I am looking for something more automated. It's a simple task so there must be something out there.

Comment: That said, I'm testing "Youtube Movie Maker". You can create a template and then create multiple videos in batch from that template. No watermark and no limits it seems...

Currently testing it, but it looks pretty good. 
Only cons I found were the UI. It's ugly and a bit confusing. (I had to watch a youtube video to find how how to create the multiple videos)

Comment: If you're fine with batch files, then ffmpeg is the de facto tool for this.

Comment: @Mulvya how do I do it with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

With ffmpeg, on Windows, create a batch file `AudiotoVid.cmd`

```
for %%A in (*.mp3 *.m4a *.wav *.flac *.ape) do ffmpeg -i "%%A" -i "c:\path\to\image.png" -map 1:v -map 0:a -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest -f mp4 "%~nA.mp4"
```

Run it in each folder that you wish to convert.

For each audio file of the given extensions. it will create a MP4 in the same folder as the audio file. This batch file does not recurse through subdirectories. If you want to do that, use the command below.

```
for /r %%A in (*.mp3 *.m4a *.wav *.flac *.ape) do ffmpeg -i "%%A" -i "c:\path\to\image.png" -map 1:v -map 0:a -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest -f mp4 "%~dpnA.mp4"
```

Copy a few of your files to a new folder and test this there first. I don't batch often.

Get FFmpeg for Windows from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/